# C# equivalent of perl's $_

Tags: c#, perl

Is there an equivalent to Perl's `$_` function? I'm rewriting some old perl scripts in C# and I never learned any perl. Heres an example of what i'm trying to figure out

```
sub copyText {
        while($_[0]){
            $_[1]->Empty();
            $_[0] = $_[1]->IsText();
            sleep(1);
         }
```

Comment: For those of us that know C#, but not perl, can you tell us what `$_` does?  Or maybe explain what you are trying to do.  Doing a strict conversion from one language to another may not have the best result.  It can be like asking how to use a screw with a hammer.

Comment: @cadrell0, `$_` isn't used in the above. `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` are the first and second elements of array `@_`. `@_` is the list of arguments passed to the sub. The elements of `@_` are aliased to the actual args (pass by ref) rather than being copies (pass by value).

Comment: @ikegami This is why I don't use perl :).  `$_[0]` references the array `@_`?  Or is OP's code wrong?

Comment: @cadrell0, I'm not sure what you mean by "reference" in that question. Arrays aren't pointers in Perl, no referencing is occurring there. But other than that, Perl's `$a[0]` is like C's `a[0]`. The array would be declared using `my @a;`. `my $a;` would be a scalar (NULL (called undef), string, signed integer, unsigned int, floating point, reference (which includes object, file handle and much more)). `my %a;` would be a hash table.

Comment: @ikegami I'm trying to figure out how someone is supposed to make the association of `$_[0]` and `@_` since the first character is different.  Logical reference, not pointer reference.

Comment: @cadrell0, It is something they changed in Perl6. Most other design decision are actually very smart. You could say `$a[0]` evaluates to a scalar (`$`) and `@a` evaluates to a list (and arrays (`@`) are list-ish), but that doesn't hold up 100%.

Comment: @cadrell0, Perl has two ways of indexing arrays. It can retrieve a single element (`$a[$i]`) or multiple elements (`@a[$i,$j,$j]`, called a slice). The different syntax is required because `$a[f()]` and `@a[f()]` evaluate `f()` in different context.

Comment: @ikegami: well that's like saying "I don't use perl becaue I don't know anything about the syntax".  To explain:  a $variable is a scalar, a `@variable` is an array, a `%variable` is an associative array.  `$variable[$i]` refers to the scalar stored in the `$i`th index of the `@variable` array.  `$variable{index}` accesses the scalar stored in the 'index' key of `%variable`.  It actually make for very clear code once one learns a little perl syntax.  However the sample function is badly written (follows poor conventions).  There are built in variables, notably `$_` (it) and `@_` (them).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, `$_` is not a function. It's just an ordinary variable (that happens to be read and changed by a lot of builtins).

Second of all, the code you posted does not use `$_`. It's accessing elements of `@_`, the parameter list.

A more more readable version of the code you posted would be:

```
sub copyText {
   my ($arg1, $arg2) = @_;
   while ($arg1) {
      $arg2->Empty();
      $arg1 = $arg2->IsText();
      sleep(1);
   }

   $_[0] = $arg1;   # arg1 is passed by reference
}
```

- arg1 is a boolean passed by reference.
- arg2 is some kind of object with a method named `Empty` and one named `IsText`.

Sorry, I don't know C#, but hopefully you can move on with this.

Comment: `$arg1` might not be a boolean. Any value evaluates to true or false in Perl. I'm guessing based on the name `IsText` and since it's only used as a boolean.

Comment: yeah its an old news scraper so i guess this was a check to see if it picked up something wrong

Comment: If you want to improve on this answer, a usage of the copyText function and how it works from the calling scope might be helpful.

Comment: @Kent Fredric, I did provide that, but I used prose instead of code because `copyText($bool, $obj)` isn't very descriptive.

Comment: I meant, in an enclosing context. ie: https://gist.github.com/4189654#file_example.pl , as it was a bit confusing having to mentally parse the code to divine its behaviour =)

Comment: p.s. I don't know if my example is even right. Make sure you correct it before stealing it =D

Comment: @Kent Fredric, 1) I don't know enough about the actors involved to be able to divine the enclosing context any more than I already have, 2) The OP should have code that calls that function already, so that would unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

> Perl's `$_` function

It's not a function. It's a pronoun meaning 'it'.

There's another special variable `@_`, which is a pronoun meaning 'them'.

There's no analogue in C#.

Comment: correspondingly $_[0] means the 0th index of them.  scalar (@_) returns the count of them etc.